# TPM backed Certificate, alternative

Tags: encryption, backup, x509certificate, data-protection, tpm

I can make a local self-signed certificate like below. I use it for encryption. No password
needed because the private key is stored in the TPM. The private key of the certificate can't be exported by design.

```
  $cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Provider "Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider" -Subject "CN=LTrust CA" -type DocumentEncryptionCert -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment,DataEncipherment,KeyAgreement -KeyExportPolicy NonExportable -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048 -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -NotAfter $((Get-Date).AddYears(10))
```

Now I can

```
$e = "1234" | Protect-CmsMessage -To $cert.Thumbprint  #Encrypt
```

And:

```
Unprotect-CmsMessage -Content $e #Decrypt
```

But when the Certificate for some reason is lost, I can't retrieve the encrypted data anymore.
So a backup is needed. But by design this is not possible, because the private key is not available for export.

I found this article about the subject:
[Creating TPM-Backed Certificates on Windows](https://polansky.co/blog/tpm-backed-certificates-windows/)

It says:

> Warning: You cannot export this key from the TPM. Ever. If you lose your PC, or if the TPM gets reset accidentally (this can happen if you use multiple operating systems and accidentally try to use it with both, or if the BIOS on your machine is reset), you will lose the key. Ensure that you have an alternate way of accessing anything you protect this way.

**So how to ensure decryption of my data in case of the TPM is reset or gone?**

Comment: You can't. That's what the warning means. The TPM is a low-end [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module). Real HSMs have mechanisms for backing up keys to other HSM instances. This makes HSM manufacturers happy because you have buy more HSMs. Note that this is less of an issue if you only use the keypair for signatures, or if you archive decrypted messages.

Comment: You should take a closer look onto Bitlocker as an example crypto system that makes use of TPM sealed crypto keys. The important fact is that you don't use the TPM key for decrypting the data but for decrypting the master key. Therefore the master key can be stored encrypted using the TPM key and additionally you can encrypt it using a different key (e.g. a password derived key). Then you have two ways to get access to the master key.

Comment: @Robert. Thanks for your suggestion. This could go for an answer!!

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk TPMs also have mechanisms for backing up keys to other TPMs, for example  `TPM_CC_Duplicate`.